# Deprecated Dependency Warning not removing

Tags: media, composer

In my Drupal 8.9.6 (Installed with Lightning distribution) Status Admin Page, there are three warnings showing after updating several modules and core to the latest versions:

1. DEPRECATED DEPENDENCY: ENTITY EMBED Lightning Media 5.0 will not include the Entity Embed module. Please add it to your project directly: composer require drupal/entity_embed:^1.0
2. DEPRECATED DEPENDENCY: VIDEO EMBED MEDIA Lightning Media 5.0 will not include the Video Embed Media module. Please add it to your project directly: composer require drupal/video_embed_field:^2.0.
3. DEPRECATED DEPENDENCY: VIEWS INFINITE SCROLL Lightning Media 5.0 will not include the Views Infinite Scroll module. Please add it to your project directly: composer require drupal/views_infinite_scroll:^1.6.

I have installed the latest versions of these contributed modules through composer. But the warning not going away from the admin status page. How to remove these warning?

Comment: did you try clearing cache and run cron.

Comment: Yeap, several times.

Answer (score 1):

The Lighting Media modules have hard-wired checks to report this information if it finds [Video Embed Media](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/lightning_media/-/blob/8.x-4.x/modules/lightning_media_video/lightning_media_video.install#L98) or [Entity Embed & Views Infinite Scroll](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/lightning_media/-/blob/1f72a8e58c3c0eef18e40a7eedf83bfdcc0922ba/lightning_media.install#L373) installed. It doesn't check the Composer requirements to see if the warning message is still applicable.

Either ignore the warning until the 5.x release is out or patch away checks in `hook_requirements()` if it bothers you that much.